# kvm doesn't load Windows 8

Tags: windows, kvm, virtualization

I'm launching kvm with the following parameter:

`kvm -m 2g -smp ncores=2 -hda disk.img -cdrom win8.iso`

My CPU has VT support and enabled,

[image]

**EDIT**

I seems to have limited emulate type:

```
pc                   Standard PC (alias of pc-1.1)
pc-1.1               Standard PC (default)
pc-1.0               Standard PC
pc-0.15              Standard PC
pc-0.14              Standard PC
pc-0.13              Standard PC
pc-0.12              Standard PC
pc-0.11              Standard PC, qemu 0.11
pc-0.10              Standard PC, qemu 0.10
isapc                ISA-only PC
```

Comment: Try different `-M` parameters.

Comment: @warl0ck: you can also try different `-cpu` values.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco amazing ! It worked, and I finally find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running 64bit OS, so KVM by default uses a 64bit Virtual CPU, so when you load x64 window 8, it works; but for a x86 win 8, you need to specify another CPU, e.g SandyBridge.